# Show url image in web resource

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a form, and I've added a new image web resource and the Photo URL textbox.  I've tried searching but, I can't seem to figure out how to write javascript to get the image from the Photo URL textbox and display the image in the web resource.

The form I am updating is the User form which doesn't seem to have a Notes section to which I could attach images too.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Basically your web resource should be HTML with a `img` control.

[Embed this HTML web resource](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/tag/html-webresource-example-in-crm-2015/) in your user entity form. In HTML, on form load you can fetch the textbox value & set the url of `img` tag.

You need `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` to read crm context & controls.

```
<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```